# tkinter windows doesn't open windows and Vs code doesn't show any errors

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from pytube import YouTube

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("YouTube donwloader")

Label(root,text='YouTube video downloader', font ='arial 20 bold').pack()

link = StringVar()
Label(root,text = 'Paste the link here', font = 'arial 15 bold').place(x=160, y = 60)
link_enter = Entry(root, width=70, textvariable= link).place(x=32, y=90)


def Downloader():
    url = YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video  = url.streams.first()
    video.donwload()
    Label(root, text = 'Donwload', font = 'arial 15 bold', bg = 'pale viloted red', command = Downloader).place(x=180, y = 150)


root.mainloop
```

When I run the program, it executes, however don't open any windows. Vs code also doesn't show errors

Comment: Forgot parentheses root.mainloop().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you never start the `mainloop`.

Change the last line to:

```
root.mainloop()
```

There are other errors, too. Note that the `place()` method always returns `None`.